# Options for VichFileType not taken into account in EasyAdmin 3 CRUD

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle, easyadmin3

I use Symfony 5.3, EasyAdmin 3.5, and Vich/Uploader-bundle 1.19
I want to manage uploads of PDF files into a EAsyAdmin CRUD controller.

Here is the configuration of my fields for this CRUD Controller

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
    return [
        Field::new('document')->setFormType(VichFileType::class, [
            'download_label' => 'Télécharger',
            'allow_delete' => false,
        ])
    ];
}
```

But in my EasyAdmin Update Page, here is my result :

[image]

It seems that the options passed in my VichFileType are not used.
Further more, the default option for 'download_label' does not use french translation provided with Vich/Upload-bundle.

Do you have any idea ? Do You thinks it's a bug from my code of from VichUpload ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by using the command

```
Field::new('document')
->setFormType(VichFileType::class)
->setFormTypeOptions(
   [
     'download_label' => 'Télécharger',
     'allow_delete' => false,
   ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the FormType, it's easier.

You put the imageFile in your form then your show the imageName in your twig.